# How Do You Have a Django App to Frequently Monitor a Remote Database

Tags: python, django, django-apps

I'm trying to build a django app that can monitor and interact with a remote database (to interact with the database in a basic way - just performing a look-up and only sometimes making a little change in the remote data), it also has to sometimes store the remote data to its own database.

The website which sits on the remote database is a community website, and anyone without an account is allowed to post on the website's forums. I want the app to be able to check the database every now and then to see for any updates in the discussions. The site gets at least 100 posts an hour and since anyone is allowed to post on the forums without an account, it occasionally gets spammed, but unfortunately the CMS that is being used does not have a good anti-spam system set up.

Only way that I can think of at the moment is to make a python file, and in that file I can import MySQLdb. I can connect to the remote database (mysql) server and select all the posts that have been made in the last X minutes. Using a function that calculates the probability of a post being a spam or not, I can again talk to the remote database and flag the candidates to be not displayed on the website. I can have this file run "every now and then" using *cron*.

The problem here is a lack of control. I want to have a user interface that can show all the spam candidates on a single webpage and have an "unflag" button to make accidentally flagged posts to be shown on that website again. This means that I'll probably be better off writing a django web app than to write a single python script that simply just flags spam candidates.

How would I have a django app or perhaps a function within that app (which can perform all actions that the stand-alone python script as described above can perform) to run automatically every now then (say every minute)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should try [django-celery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery)?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I've seen some examples on its website, and it looks quite promising. Looks like I can put a decorator over a function and have only that function to be run by celery. I'll definitely have to give this a try.